# .Net Security Zone Permission Sets?

Tags: .net, .net-security

Can someone help me to find web-page or resource where can I see what permissions does each zone have?:

Internet Zone
My Computer
and others.

before .net 4.0 I was able to see them in .net configuration tool, but it is not included in .net 4.0 and I cannot find it in v2.0 folder too.
exampele:
in .net configuration tool there was window where I was able to see that:
Internet Zone permissions: File Dialogs, Printing, etc...
please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security in .NET 4.0 has been completely redesigned. There are sever articles on the MSDN on this, a good starting point is [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-code-access-security-in-.net-framework-4.0---part-i/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2010/02/24/so-is-cas-dead-in-net-4-or-what.aspx)

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103) also gives an overview of security on .NET 4.0

Comment: Well I couldn't find a full list, however you should be able to still  use the configuration utility after installing the .NET 2.0 SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19988)

Comment: Here, have a bounty. It turned out, however, that this question was not really about what I thought it was when I decided to boost it. If you like, could you have a look at [my attempt to ask the right question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841410/what-can-a-clickonce-application-in-an-internet-zone-sandbox-expect-to-get-away) instead?